# When HttpStatusCodeException exception raised?

Tags: java, spring, rest, httpexception

when i use below code , what is the case to get `HttpStatusCodeException` exception .

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = 
  restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
```

Please can anyone help out ????????

Comment: I need to create case where  HttpStatusCodeException is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP Status Codes are responses from the server, therefore if you have control of the server then you could make it return whichever errors you want. If you don't have control of the server then you could try sending bad/invalid requests so that the server will complain.

Something like this on your server side:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getAnError() {
    // complain!
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
  ResponseEntity<ShippingPreferenceBo> response = bodyBuilder.build();  i used like this but no use

Comment: @Nag-Raj Edited. Try something like that.

Answer (score 12):

According to documentation there are two types of `HttpStatusCodeException`  `HttpClientErrorException` and `HttpServerErrorException`.

- The former is thrown when an HTTP 4xx is received.
- The latter is thrown when an HTTP 5xx is received.

so you can just use ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder.status(505) for example to raise an `HttpServerErrorException` in your

Comment: BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
  ResponseEntity<ShippingPreferenceBo> response = bodyBuilder.build();  i used like this but no use

Answer (score 8):

exhange(...) method of `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` class was added in `3.1.0.RELEASE` of spring-web library.

This method throws `RestClientException` which covers client (4_xx) and server (5_xx) side http code errors. But `RestClientException` doesn't offer `getStatusCode(), getResponseAsString()`, etc... methods.

1. `HttpsStatusCodeException` is the child of `RestClientException`  which is doing same thing but with additional methods like `getStatusCode(), getResponseAsString()`, etc.
2. `HttpClientErrorException` child of `HttpsStatusCodeException` and only entertain client error (4_xx) not the server error.
3. `HttpServerErrorException` child of `HttpsStatusCodeException` and only entertain server error (5_xx) not the client error.